# How we install Apache and Nginx together and check default page as both uses same port 80

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, apache2, 16.04, nginx

$sudo apt-get install apache2

$Sudo apt-get install nginx

Both installed but only apache is running and if we go for nginx after stopping service of apache ,nginx service is running but not showing its default page!!
Please help to resolve

Comment: You can't listen to same port with two different web servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't listen to same port with two servers but if you want you can configure Nginx as a reverse proxy for apache. 
Here is a great tutorial to do that https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache.
You can also check this one http://kbeezie.com/apache-with-nginx/ .

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been stated above, it is impossible to run different services on the same port as only one service can run on a port at a time. You can however run Nginx as  a proxy server (each one running on a different port).

Note: you can configure each server's document root to load different home pages when both are running on different port (if that is what you want).

Comment: The question is about how both apache and nginx would work at the same time while both are listening to the same port. I put localhost in the browser. How would they mange to serve at the same time? I think you are not addressing the problem

Comment: i was trying to provide alternative means of achieving the aim of the question, however my answer has been edited to reveal that.